# Manually adding Gradle resources in offline mode (in Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

After moving to China recently (i.e. last week), I set up Android Studio on a new computer. Because of the "Great Firewall of China," I'm having serious issues building projects. I get error messages from both Gradle Sync and Gradle Build. Here are my message dumps:

Gradle Sync

```
C:\Users\Lars\AndroidStudioProjects\ChatClientColors\app\build.gradle
Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1
Error:Failed to resolve: javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1
Error:Failed to resolve: junit:junit-dep:4.10
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
Error:Failed to resolve: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
```

Gradle Build

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugAndroidTestCompile'.
   > Could not resolve junit:junit-dep:4.10.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test:runner:0.2
      > Could not resolve junit:junit-dep:4.10.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit-dep/4.10/junit-dep-4.10.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit-dep/4.10/junit-dep-4.10.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.1.1/javawriter-2.1.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.1/hamcrest-integration-1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.1/hamcrest-integration-1.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.1/hamcrest-library-1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.1/hamcrest-library-1.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1.
     Required by:
         ChatClientColors:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1
      > Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/hamcrest-core-1.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/hamcrest-core-1.1.pom'.
               > peer not authenticated
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.0 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

The problem seems to be that the HTTPS handshake doesn't go through (had the same problem with downloading sdk packages, but that could be circumvented using a proxy).
I've researched the issue of on-demand dependencies a bit, but I haven't found the one solution that fits this problem. The Gradle offline mode doesn't help much if I haven't downloaded the resources before - it merely tells me that I need to turn the offline mode off to resolve the dependencies...

The info I've found on stackoverflow and elsewhere was mostly referring to very early Gradle versions and stated that there is no way to run Gradle "offline-only." But can't those few resources (.pom files?) be downloaded manually? If so, where can I put them - the .gradle directory? Do I need to create subfolders? Do I need to tell Gradle that I've downloaded the resources, or is that implied in the use of the offline mode?

Help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably paid vpn would be most comfortable way

Comment: I am having similar issues and for certain reasons, a VPN is not an option for me.